# How to search within an argument and output a certain value

Tags: python, search, find, arguments

I have the following script and I can't get it to search for a string and then output the value.

How do I take the Argument and Split it up so I can search for "endpoint-machine-name=" and then output its value?

Here is the command:

```
python -u HostnameScript.py "discover-repository-location=null, Employee Notified=null, Manager     Title=Exec Dir Biostatistics, date-detected=Mon Aug 25 16:03:35 PDT 2014, endpoint-machine-name=Davidpc, incident-id=603, sender-ip=null, Machine Name=null, Assigned To=null, Business Unit=Development US"
```

I have tried splitting it up, but can't search it correctly.

```
import sys, socket, string, commands, os, re, subprocess

arguments=sys.argv[1:]

for args in [item.split(", ") for item in arguments[]:
 if item.find("endpoint-machine-name=") != -1
 value=item.strip("endpoint-machine-name=")
 sys.stdout.write('Hostname=');print value
```

All I end up getting is

```
Hostname=discover-repository-location=null, Employee Notified=null, Manager Title=Exec Dir Biostatistics, date-detected=Mon Aug 25 16:03:35 PDT 2014, endpoint-machine-name=Davidpc, incident-id=603, sender-ip=null, Machine Name=null, Assigned To=null, Business Unit=Development US
```

Comment: Indenting with a single space and putting unrelated statements together on one line with semicolons makes your code very hard to read. Also, there's at least two `SyntaxError`s and an `IndentationError` in your code; can you paste a [running, minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Meanwhile, there's one pretty obvious bug in your code: you're searching for `"endpoint-machin-name="`, but your data have `"endpoint-machine-name="`, which isn't the same string.

Comment: what is `argument[]`?

Comment: Anyway, it seems like your bug is a combination of (1) your typo in the search string means that nothing matches, (2) you're using `item` instead of the `args` that should be the result of splitting each `item`, and (3) your `sys.stdout.write` is probably indented wrong so that it's outside the `if`. As a combination of those three bugs, for every item, no matter what, you print the whole item preceded by `Hostname=`, which describes your output. But without seeing the _actual_ code, I can't show you how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry about all of that.. those are all typos on my part.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
import sys

pairs = sys.argv[1]

for p in pairs.split(', '):
    if 'endpoint-machine-name=' in p:
        print p.replace('endpoint-machine-name=', 'Hostname=')
        break
```

...or, if you really want to parse the pairs:

```
import sys

pairs = sys.argv[1]

for p in pairs.split(', '):
    k, v = p.split('=', 1)

    if k == 'endpoint-machine-name':
        print 'Hostname={0}'.format(v)
        break
```

Of course, you'll have issues if the string `', '` appears anywhere in your
values.  Also, `strip` does not function in that way.  `strip`
takes a string as an argument which represents the *set* of characters which
should be stripped from the string, not a specific ordered sequence of
characters.

If, as you mention, you need to use the functionality in some other script, make it into a stand-alone function:

```
import sys

function find_host(pairs):
    for p in pairs.split(', '):
        k, v = p.split('=', 1)

        if k == 'endpoint-machine-name':
            print 'Hostname={0}'.format(v)
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_host(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: This works fine with the command line.. but when I use it with a program that calls the script it needs to use.. pairs = sys.argv[1:] and this where I have issues. Python is called and has 1 long command. Any idea how to get it to work with that?

Answer (score 0):

All thanks for you help.. I figured it out with you help of course.

Here is the code I used.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

value2 = sys.argv[1:]


for p in value2:
    if 'policy-name=' in p:
            print p.replace('policy-name=','Policy Name=')
    if 'date-detected=' in p:
            print p.replace('date-detected=','Event Date=')
```